# How can I search a column with alphanumeric entries and return a 1 for unique with an array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need something that auto-fills for however many rows are in the spreadsheet, but I'm not sure if an array is the best way.

In my example below, I want `Column C` to show a `1` if the corresponding entry in `Column A` is unique, and a `0` if it isn't.

I had hoped it would be as easy as using `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(UNIQUE(A1:A),1,0))`, but forgot that IF wouldn't work with the text.

[Here's my example with the most recent formula I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sdS7.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A1:A)<>0, 
      IF(COUNTIF(A1:A,A1:A)>1,0,1)
                                ,""))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)

Comment: Thank you! Did just what I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

### You can combine `ARRAYFORMULA` and `IF` with `IFERROR` and `COUNTIF`

Sample:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(COUNTIF(A1:A,A1:A)=1,0)=TRUE,1,0))`